Properties of the function $ f(x):= \displaystyle\prod_{n=0}^{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor-1} (x-n). $
The following function on $[1,\infty)$ is clearly continuous and increasing (although admittedly I have not provided a proof of these things), as small increases in $x$ give small increases in $f$:
$$ f(x):= \displaystyle\prod_{n=0}^{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor-1} (x-n). $$
I am interested in properties of this function, as I came across it whilst studying the closed form of products such as $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right).$ The function $f(x)$ is different to but somewhat related to the Gamma function, since $f$ passes through the points $(n, n!),$ similar to the Gamma function. The Gamma function probably has nicer properties in $\mathbb{C},$ otherwise this function would be more famous. So why is this function not famous?
In $\mathbb{R}$, is $f$ differentiable (how many times?) or convex? In particular, we only get potential problems when $x$ is an integer. I would ask if it's analytic if we extended the function to $\mathbb{C}$ somehow, but it has been a while since I studied complex analysis, so this is beyond my current capabilities.
Edit: Assuming this graph is correct, the function looks non-differentiable at the integers. There is also a connection to the Gamma function: $f(x)=\frac{\Gamma(1 + x)}{\Gamma\left(1 + x - \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\right)}.$

See what happens when x goes to x+1

This product seems $C^{\infty}$ everywhere excepts on $\mathbb{Z}$. (Since the upper bound in the product is constant in a $[n,n+1[$ interval $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.)

@martycohen $f(x+1)=(x+1)f(x).$ What's your point?

There is no discontinuity at the integers.

Note that $f(x)=1$ on $[0,1)$ and $f(x)=x$ on $[1,2)$ and $f(x)=x(x-1)$ on $[2,3)$; it follows that $f$ is continuous but not differentable at $x=1$, and once but not twice differentiable at $x=2$. I'm guessing $f$ is $n-1$ but not $n$ times differentiable at $x=n$ for every integer $n\ge1$.

@GregMartin Great observation! I didn't think of that.

Why is it diff at $x=2$ ? Left and right difff does not match (resp. $1 \neq 3$)

@EDX I think you might be right about that (although I'm too tired to check), but Greg is right about the first thing he said.

Yes lets sleep and see later :)
